# C#, method that outputs multiple value

Tags: c#

I am using c#.

I have a method that outputs multiple values. I am aware of **out** but this is a reference type.
Is there anything equivalent to value type but that can also output multiple values from a method. With the reference type, the values are also changed outside of the method so I like to prevent.

```
    out
```

Comment: `out` may be for reference types, but value types get boxed automatically into objects when used with `out`.

Comment: Can you not wrap the return of the method in your own type?

Comment: @Cameron: … **if** the parameter type is `object`. You can use value types directly for `out` parameters and avoid boxing.

Comment: @Douglas: Oh cool, I didn't know that. But, the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) say: `The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference.` **EDIT** OHHH, they mean pass-by-reference, not pass-as-reference-type. My mistake! ;-)

Comment: @Cameron: Yes, that’s a very common source of confusion among .NET developers. Sometimes I wish that Microsoft had chosen more discriminative naming rather than re-using the term “reference” for two distinct contexts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am aware of **out** but this is a reference type.

It's not clear what you mean. `out` isn't a type at all - it's a decorator for parameters. You can use it with reference types or value types:

```
// Nasty, but it does work...
void SplitInTwo(string input, out string x1, out string x2, 
                out int actualSplitCount)
{
    string[] bits = input.Split('/');
    x1 = bits[0];
    x2 = bits[1];
    actualSplitCount = bits.Length;
}
```

So you *can* use `out` either way. However, I would strongly advise you *not* to do so. You can use the `Tuple` family of types for ad hoc multiple values, but if the returned values are actually related, you should consider encapsulating them into a separate type, and returning a value of that type.

Comment: Jon, I thought like ref, out was also a reference type. Is out a value type?

Comment: @NatePet: `ref` is not a type, either. It simply means the parameter is *passed by reference*. This is different from whether or not the type itself is a *reference type* or a *value type*.

Comment: @NatePet: I think you're a bit confused about ref/out. Read my article on parameter passing: http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating a class that describes your return value and has properties for each value you need to return.

Tuple is a decent option if you don't need to pass the result around often, but in general it's harder to maintain. I prefer working with meaningful property names rather than the Item1, Item2, Item3, etc. that Tuple provides. The out parameters also work, but they require the calling code to be written differently to accommodate the method implementation, which I recommend avoiding whenever possible.

Comment: If @Nate have to be sure thats type isn't reference type  - make `struct` it's seems like class but it's simple type not reference;)

Answer (score 0):

The `out` keyword (and `ref` keyword) are used to indicate that a variable is provided from the caller's scope. They don't change the nature of the type in question.

[out parameter modifier (C# Reference) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx)

If you're concerned requiring the caller being forced to specify `out` every time they use your method, you can use a Helper class or a `Tuple` to wrap the set of values returned.

[Tuple Class @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)

You mention that you are concerned about reference-types being changed. This shouldn't be an issue to your method. The parameter specified by `out` is not shared by all cases where your method may used, they're local to the scope where your method is called. Only the caller needs to worry, and only in their own scope.

Last, if you want to indicate that a variable may be altered or used without being required to assign a value to it as `out` requires, use `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of :

```
class MultiValue
{
    type A {
        get { return m_A; }
        set { m_A = value; }
    }

    type B{
        get { return m_B; }
        set { m_B = value; }
    }

    private type m_A;
    private type m_B;
}
```

Could work depending on what you're trying to do (Returns the value in a single instance or if you need to maintain those values over a period of time / methods).

But the `Tuple` types would also accomplish a similar effect, again, with better results depending what you want to do in your program.