# How do I output multiple values from a method, and still follow proper design principles?

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have a method that requires more that two output values.

My options would be the following (maybe there are more options I haven't considered)

- return value along with multiple out/ref parameters
- create a class that would hold each output value I want and my method will return that
- construct an XML string that contains all the output values I want and return that

I'm asking because i remember reading somewhere that it not good to use out and ref parameters.  But I'm not sure how else to do it.

Which way adheres best to design principles and also makes it better for unit testing?
Also are there other options I didn't list that would be acceptable?

EDIT: the extra output values I'm considering to return in addition to the main value, have to do with success failure condition of the process as well as the name of the condition that failed etc.  So mostly for tracking and testing of the process.

Comment: I always apply SRP-Single Responsibility Principle to methods as i do classes, a method should only do one thing, and return one thing.

Comment: @Bit Yes I agree, I clarified what the extra values were that i wanted in my original post.  So really the main return value is only one that the client interacts with.  The rest are for our own testing and debugging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would rank your options this way:

1. create a class that would hold each output value I want and my method will return that
2. return value along with multiple out/ref parameters
3. construct an XML string that contains all the output values I want

However, all of these represent a "code smell" that your method is doing too much.  At least returning a class indicates that the method is providing several known, related values.  Using `out`/`ref` is more of a workaround (sometimes they're valid, sometimes they're not) to avoid creating a class, and XML is not a good choice since you force the consumer to know the schema in order to extract the values.

Comment: well many of the output values I'm thinking of including in addition to the main output value have to do with capturing the success or failure of a process (like return 1 if success, 0 if failed, along with the name of the settings that failed etc)

Comment: @Asad Fair enough, but it depends on the values that are returned.  If they are logically related and grouped into a reasonable class, then I agree.  I was thinking more of the scenario of returning "The result of a calculation, a status message, and the current amount of disk space available".

Comment: @erotavlas It's hard to say without knowing more about your design and requirements, but there may be "better" ways to get that info.  For example, could the status be a property of the class that runs the process?

Comment: @DStanley Well that's a good idea, but the method in my class loops through a series of values, so if I used a property in the class, it would keep getting overwritten. Unless I store in some other data type, like a List of something and keep adding to it.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the accepted solution for doing this would be your second bullet point, create an object with all the return data.

`out`/`ref` has a very specific semantic associated with it, that you are going to give it some pre-made "things" that the function is expected to modify/set. This isn't the same thing as a return value.

Using an XML string is no better than returning a dictionary or custom object, and is far more confusing.

Another neat option (almost tailor made for this) would be to use a `Tuple`. Say you want to return an `int` and `string`, you could return a `Tuple<int, string>`. This is a quick way to get an "anonymous" return object. If you are going to reuse it at all though, a named object is better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ref` keyword, Custom `class` and `XML` go for `Tuple`.

```
return new Tuple<int, string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the Tuple family of types for ad hoc multiple values, but if the returned values are actually related, you should consider encapsulating them into a separate type, and returning a value of that type.

Jon Skeet mentioned that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11144413/3637535). Also, as David Crowell mentioned, `struct` is also a good choice. Being a value type it has some (Albeit very minor) advantages over a class.

Comment: A struct almost certainly should *not* be used here, as it meets virtually none of the criteria for when to use a `struct`.  Most important of which is the fact that this does not conceptually represent a single value.

Answer (score -3):

For just a few values, what about a struct?

```
struct ReturnType
{
    int id;
    string name;
}
```

Comment: What does using a struct have to do with how few (or many) attributes the return type needs to have? What benefits does this have over a class?

Comment: A struct is lighter weight than a class.  You return the struct type rather than several values.

Comment: structs should represent a *single* value, not a group of values.  They should be immutable.  They should not be large in size.  You've met virtually none of the metrics by which one determines if they should use a `struct`.  About the only thing you got right is that this is unlikely to be boxed, but you're missing pretty much all of the rest.